# How to add if conditions in hibernate criteria while using restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning hibernate criteria queries. I want to use hibernate criteria query for searching purpose. 
Below is my searching fields

**Searching fields**
[image: Searching fields]

And here is my code for searching

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(
        Restrictions.and(
        Restrictions.ilike("firstName", firstName),
        Restrictions.ilike("lastName", lastName)
        )
    );
```

Problem I am facing is while searching with only firstName It will take lastName as empty string and due to "AND" condition between firstName and lastName. Its not getting any matched result. Now I want to add condition so that if any field of search is empty or null then it will be not included in query. 
Basically I am working in grails so in grails this will be achieve like this

```
def userList = userCriteria.list{
    and{    
        if(firstName) {
            like('firstName',firstName)
        }
        if(lastName) {
            like('lastName',lastName)
        }
       }
}
```

I want to do same with hibernate criteria query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Strings.isBlankOrNull(firstName)) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("firstName", firstName));
}
if (!Strings.isBlankOrNull(lastName)) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("lastName", lastName));
}
```

Note that you're learning an [old, deprecated, proprietary, abandoned API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria). You'd better learn the standard JPA criteria API.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, currently I am using 4.3.11. So should I move to hibernate 5.1 version?